# My loop won't execute?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ManySubstrings {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String line;
        int sub, length;
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a string: ");
        line = kb.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter substring length: ");
        sub = kb.nextInt();
        length = line.length();

        for(int i=0; i< length;i=+sub){
            System.out.println(line.substring(i,sub));
            sub= + sub;
        }
    }
}
```

Expected output

```
 Enter a string: anthropomorphization
 Enter substring length: 3
 "ant"
 "nth" 
 "thr"
 "hro"
 "rop"
 "opo"
 "pom"
 "omo"
 "mor"
 "orp"
 "rph"
 "phi"
 "hiz"
 "iza"
 "zat"
 "ati"
 "tio"
 "ion"
```

I need a "for" loop to go through the length of the word with substring length defined by the user to get all substrings of the word to the end

Comment: Looks like you are using `=+` in your loop instead of `+=`.  Please try to step through problems in a debugger to catch simple typos...

Comment: Why did you post the Java code in the form of a lot of HTML?

Comment: Because it was just easier for me to post it from the syntax highlighter.

Comment: @44hz answer posted for your acceptance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can change your `for` to this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < length - sub + 1; i++){
    System.out.println(line.substring(i, i + sub));
}
```

What this does is iterating from first character to third from last and always `substring`-ing from index to index + `sub`.

Comment: where exactly does the first index point get assigned to its next value. wouldn't the second time around be (1, i+sub) since i only got incremented once in the condition or am I missing something.

Comment: You are missing something. Incrementing `i` is all you need here, and `for` loop does that for you.

Comment: wow I was in the kitchen and it finally hit me, since you are subtracting from length this pulls it all together

Comment: @44hz: Glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String line;
    int sub, length;
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a string: ");
    line = kb.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Enter substring length: ");
    sub = kb.nextInt();
    length = line.length();

    for (int i = 0 ; i < length - (sub - 1) ; i++) { // no need to loop it to end of string length
        if (i + sub <= length)
            System.out.println(line.substring(i, i + sub));
    }
}
```

**Ouput**

```
Enter a string: anthropomorphization
Enter substring length: 3
ant
nth
thr
hro
rop
opo
pom
omo
mor
orp
rph
phi
hiz
iza
zat
ati
tio
ion
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution:

You almost had it correct, notice the way the loop is configured.
Your solution was trying to be overly clever with the loop and was overly complex.

Also notice how proper formatting makes the code easier to read.

Of note is the condition that we don't loop to the complete end of the string.

#### Important:

We stop at `< line.length() -(sub - 1)` because we would index past the end of the String and get an exception if we went any further.

```
public static void main(final String[] args)
{
    final Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a string: ");
    final String line = kb.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Enter substring length: ");
    final int sub = kb.nextInt();

    for (int i = 0; i < line.length() - (sub-1); i++)
    {
        System.out.println(line.substring(i,i+sub));
    }

    // abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
}
```

#### Outputs:

```
Enter a string: abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
Enter substring length: 3
abc
bcd
cde
def
efg
fgh
ghi
hij
ijk
jkl
klm
lmn
mno
nop
opq
pqr
qrs
rst
stu
tuv
uvw
vwx
wxy
xyz
```

#### And:

```
Enter a string: abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
Enter substring length: 5
abcde
bcdef
cdefg
defgh
efghi
fghij
ghijk
hijkl
ijklm
jklmn
klmno
lmnop
mnopq
nopqr
opqrs
pqrst
qrstu
rstuv
stuvw
tuvwx
uvwxy
vwxyz
```

Answer (score -1):

this code is complicated and the cause why your sub double each loop

```
   sub= + sub;
```

use ++ instead in incrementing sub

```
for(int i=0; i< length; i = sub){
    System.out.println(line.substring(i,sub));
    sub++;
}
```